# Почему боксерские - перчатки?

Tags: лексика

Думаю, все знают знаменитое:

> "Если помидор — ягода, можно ли
> называть кетчуп вареньем? И как
> красота может спасти мир, если она все
> время требует жертв? И если мазохист
> попадает в ад, то он попадает в рай? И
> почему боксерские перчатки называют
> перчатками, если они — варежки?"

А действительно, почему боксерские - перчатки?

Comment: Уж  скорее  боевые  рукавицы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Боксёрские перчатки пришли к нам из Англии, их ввёл Джонс Браутон (Броутон) как экипировку, защищающую от травм: "boxing gloves" переводилось как перчатки. Никаких вариантов — рукавицы, варежки, голицы — не было.
Вероятно, термин *перчатка* был взят из истории, от гладиаторов, забинтовывавших руки сыромятными ремнями (и ещё до них это было известно). Поначалу это и были перчатки, потому что забинтовывали пальцы отдельно, потом соединяли вместе.
В русском языке даже есть слово-историзм *перчатка* — железный предохранительный футляр для руки, надевавшийся рыцарями на время битвы (истор.).
Когда появились современные в Англии (по виду они были похожи на те исторические, и функция та же — защита от травм), зачем придумывать новое название? А вот в быту для защиты от повреждений и холода — варежки, голицы и ещё много разных названий.

Comment: Спортивную  принадлежность  заимствовали  вместе  с  названием.